# Pandas dataframe rolling sum column with groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science, rolling-sum

I'm trying to create a new column that gives a rolling sum of values in the `Values` column. The rolling sum includes 4 rows i.e. the current row and the next three rows. I want to do this for each type in the 'Type' column.

However, if there are fewer than 4 rows before the next type starts, I want the rolling sum to use only the remaining rows. For example, if there are 2 rows after the current row for the current type, a total of 3 rows is used for the rolling sum. See the table below showing what I'm currently getting and what I expect.

| Index | Type | Value | Current Rolling Sum | Expected Rolling Sum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | left | 5 | 22 | 22 |
| 2 | left | 9 | 34 | 34 |
| 3 | left | 0 | NaN | 25 |
| 4 | left | 8 | NaN | 25 |
| 5 | left | 17 | NaN | 17 |
| 6 | straight | 7 | 61 | 61 |
| 7 | straight | 4 | 77 | 77 |
| 8 | straight | 0 | 86 | 86 |
| 9 | straight | 50 | 97 | 97 |
| 10 | straight | 23 | NaN | 47 |
| 11 | straight | 13 | NaN | 24 |
| 12 | straight | 11 | NaN | 11 |

The following line of code is what I'm currently using to get the rolling sum.

```
rolling_sum = df.groupby('Type', sort=False)['Value'].rolling(4, min_periods = 3).sum().shift(-3).reset_index()
rolling_sum = rolling_sum.rename(columns={'Value': 'Rolling Sum'})

extracted_col = rolling_sum['Rolling Sum']
df = df.join(extracted_col)
```

I would really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try running the rolling sum on the reversed values for each group and then reverse back afterward, using a `min_periods` of 1:

```
df['Rolling Sum'] = df.groupby('Type', sort=False)['Value'].apply(lambda x: x[::-1].rolling(4, min_periods=1).sum()[::-1])
```

Result:

```
   Index        Type    Value   Rolling Sum
0      1        left        5          22.0
1      2        left        9          34.0
2      3        left        0          25.0
3      4        left        8          25.0
4      5        left       17          17.0
5      6    straight        7          61.0
6      7    straight        4          77.0
7      8    straight        0          86.0
8      9    straight       50          97.0
9     10    straight       23          47.0
10    11    straight       13          24.0
11    12    straight       11          11.0
```

Comment: @runraver: No problems, happy to help :)

Comment: after a full day looking for a working solution, it's finally here! thanks!